# How to set an element ID to a table cell in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

In fact, I have 2 Qs:
I'm usign jqgrid and I have a column with a custom checkbox formatter (say `Passed`), a cloumn named ID and some other columns.

Q 1) I want to set IDs to cells of `Passed` column and it should be the value of `ID` column cells. Any idea?

Q 2) How can I change the value of `Passed` column cells with jquery?

extra notes: 
1) In fact, I'm using the MvcJqGrid in my MVC 4 project and I'm trying to handle change events of those checkboxes, to finally be able to get their values and send to related controller.

2) My Main problem is that I can't set correct or any values to those checkboxes or grid cells according to clicks on them.

For now, as a defeated try, my formatter is like this:

```
function pass(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="' + cellvalue + '" checked="checked" onclick="chkChange(\'' + cellvalue + '\', \'#' + cellvalue + '\')" />';
}
```

for now, I push the `ID` cells values to the `Passed` cells and it works as expected.
and the event func:

```
function chkChange(bval, id) {        
    if (bval != 'false')
        $(id).val('false');
    else
        $(id).val('true');        
}
```

By this code, I can't change the value of checkboxes. I think that maybe I should manipulate cell values instead of checkboxes. If so, it seems that the solution of this issue is the answer of my `Q 2`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't I get the parents of checkboxes with jquery and work with them?! If so, how...?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Damn...! waisting 12 hours of my time...

I changed the formatter like this:

```
function pass(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {        
    return '<input type="checkbox" id="' + cellvalue + '" checked="checked" onclick="chkChange(\'#' + cellvalue + '\')" />';
}
```

and the event func like this:

```
function chkChange(id) {                
 if ($(id).val() != 'false')
    $(id).val('false');
 else
    $(id).val('true');       
}
```

and that damned bug goes away...